# Update SQL rows one row at a time

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am trying to do a mass update on our SQL server which would easily be done by the following code in our situation.

```
update patient set security_level = '2'
where security_level = '1'
```

The problem is our SQL server connects to a mirth server that sends transactions to the State and the mirth server locks up if more than one row is updated at a time, so I'm hoping there is a way to update the rows one at a time. To prevent that our vendor who makes the software has several triggers in place. A piece of the code for the trigger is

```
IF (@numrows > 1) 
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SELECT @errmsg = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ' : more than one row is updated in table Patient'                                 
    RAISERROR(@errmsg,16,21) 
    RETURN
END
```

If I were to disable the 3 triggers it would break other things. Thank you for any suggestions or thoughts you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @tmp_table table(
PRG int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
patient_id int
)

declare @start_value int = 1,
 @finish_value int,
 @patient_id int

Insert Into @tmp_table(patient_id ) Select patient_id  From patient where  security_level = '1'

Select @finish_value = max(PRG) From  @tmp_table

While @start_value <= @finish_value 
Begin
  --now get a key for patient and store in variables
  Select @patient_id =  patient_id 
  From  @tmp_table
  Where PRG = @start_value 

  --.. and now update by key
  Update patient
  set security_level = '2'
  Where patient_id  = @patient_id 


Set @start_value = @start_value  + 1
End
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@finish_value".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@start_value".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 28
Must declare the scalar variable "@start_value".

Comment: I'm getting the error above. I'm a bit over my head, so don't want to make guesses on the error. Thank you for the help.

Comment: My fault. I can't know the key columns in patient table.with <...> i would indicate <declare here all column that are key for your table>, same for @<declare here all column that are key for your table but this time as variables>. You've to substitute all the <..> sections with right values. If u report here Keys column names and types i complete the query.

Comment: so the primary key is patient_id and the secondary is episode_id which indicates they had left and returned, so it's always a max episode situation when we are doing reporting on current data. Still having a hard time visualizing things.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.